# YA/children's Sci-Fi novel with CGI baby head against purple and yellow sky

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel, cgi

I am looking for a book I vividly remember seeing in my school library when I was a child. I am assuming the book is a 90s/00s book. All I remember was the cover, and something nagged me that it was also sci-fi.

The cover has some sort of CGI baby head (or android head) face up at the bottom of the cover, and the backdrop is some sort of strangely colored sky/sky-esque pattern that I remember being violet/yellow, but I could be wrong.

I wish I could say more. I have been digging YA sci fi book lists for the past hour.

Comment: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/telletubbies/images/d/d4/Sun_Baby_Intro.PNG/revision/latest?cb=20200319185815 ?

Comment: [Maybe it was the floating baby head from the *Phineas and Ferb* cartoons.](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Giant_Floating_Baby_Head)  There were some books (and maybe comics) made from the cartoon series.

Comment: "Face up" how, exactly? Is the baby turned towards us, do we see them *en profil*, are they looking up or merely turned upwards? Do you remember in what way the CGI was obvious (could you see polygons, was the lighting or shading off)?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be one of the covers from [2001 A Space Odyssey](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?2485) or [2010: Odyssey 2](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?2484), by Arthur C. Clarke? There are a couple of covers from 2001 that feature a baby head with a coloured background, and many editions from 2010 that feature the same cover.

![image]

[image]

The original cover for 2001 is (I think) [this one](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/2/2d/SPCDSSWXRQ1968.jpg) with a man's face in a space-suit and coloured lights playing over the shield.

2010 Odyssey 2 cover:

[image]